# Read text files into multiple list boxes c#

Tags: c#, listbox

I need my app to put different lines/data from a text file into different list boxes. Right now I've written code that load all the data/lines into one listbox:

```
public void OnLoad
{
OpenFileDialog load = new OpenFileDialog();

            //load.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
            load.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            load.FilterIndex = 2;
            load.RestoreDirectory = true;

            if (load.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                try
                {
                        List<string> lines = new List<string>(); 
                        using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(load.OpenFile())) 
                        {
                            string line; 
                            while((line = stream.ReadLine()) != null)
                            {
                                lb1.Items.Add(line); 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
}
```

I want the different list boxes to contain the lines/data that starts with the same two letters as they do.

Any ideas?

Comment: So how do you want to split up the lines, and what other list boxes are available?

Comment: So where is your problem? Since you can do it with 1 listbox doing it with 2 or more shouldnt be that hard? What do you actually want from us?

Comment: How many listboxes you have? How many lines you have in the file? Which line goes to which listbox?

Comment: What is your criteria for sorting the lines into different list boxes?

Comment: So what problem are you having?  You seem to know how to read data from a file and you seem to know how to update a ListBox.  What, specifically, is giving you trouble?

Comment: ``if (line.Substring(2) == "AB")``

Comment: side note: wrap your `OpenFileDialog load` within a `using` statement

Comment: @RandRandom `if (line.StartsWith("AB"))`

Comment: @CallumLinington or so...

Comment: My problem is that I don't want the method to read all data from a file and put it into one listbox. For example if one of my boxes name is MVInputs I want it to contain all the data in the txt-file that starts with MV and I want all data that starts with SS to be put in SSInputs and so on. @ChrisDunaway

Comment: @Anna: So... `if (line.StartsWith("MV")) { MVInputs.Items.Add(line); } else if (line.StartsWith("SS")) { ..... }` and so on.  Or maybe grab the first two letters into a variable and `switch` on that variable.  Or any similar approach.  You seem to know what it is you want to do, where are you actually stuck?

Comment: @David maybe searching for a more "dynamic" way that respects the naming convention for the listboxes.

Comment: @RandRandom: Also a valid approach.  Could easily be overkill if there are only a few list boxes, we don't really know at this time.  But if that's the question being asked, then the OP should really be asking it.

Comment: @RandRandom Yes exactly! Sorry if I wasn't so clear about my issue. I'm not the best at programming

Answer (score 1):

So you want to group by the first two letters? Presuming you need dynamic `ListBoxes` too:

```
var twoLetterGroups = File.ReadLines(load.FileName)
   .Where(l => l.Length >= 2)
   .GroupBy(l => l.Substring(0, 2), StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
   .Select(g => new { FirstTwoLetters = g.Key, Lines = g.ToArray()})
   .ToArray();

ListBox[] listboxes = Enumerable.Range(0, twoLetterGroups.Length).Select(i => new ListBox()).ToArray();
for (int i = 0; i < twoLetterGroups.Length; i++)
{
    listboxes[i].Items.AddRange(twoLetterGroups[i].Lines);
}
// add listboxes to form
```